# Can a client cancel a Web Api request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, cancellation-token

I have the following method in my web api controller (the long running methods honor cancellation tokens, i.e. they won't run if cancellation has been requested):

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ApiMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await LongRunningNetworkOperation1(cancellationToken);
    await LongRunningNetworkOperation2(cancellationToken);

    return Ok();
}
```

The client has the following code to call my web api controller:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);

    try
    {
        // Sending DELETE request
        HttpResponseMessage deleteMessage = await httpClient.
                             DeleteAsync("http://localhost:80/api/apiMethod");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Timeout occurred.
    }
}
```

If the client's request times out before "LongRunningNetworkOperation2" is called, will the cancellationToken prevent "LongRunningNetworkOperation2" from running? In other word's, can the client signal the web api to stop running a certain request?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> can the client signal the web api to stop running a certain request?

In theory, yes. A cancellation of the `HttpClient` should close the underlying TCP/IP connection. In response, the ASP.NET stack should detect the loss of its client, and cancel the WebAPI `CancellationToken`.

In practice, it depends on how complete the `HttpClient` and `WebAPI` implementations are that you're using. Cancellation isn't necessarily *guaranteed*, but I expect it would work at least for the desktop `HttpClient`.

Comment: do you know of any place where this specific cancellation behavior is documented?

Comment: @Nick: The search on the asp.net website is not working right now, so I'm not sure if it's actually officially documented or not.

Comment: This has a word on cancellation behavior when the client is a browser -- https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/07/19/cancelling-long-running-queries-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-api.aspx