# Is it possible to cancel a specific request?

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

`HttpClient` has the method... `CancelPendingRequests`, which will,

> Cancel all pending requests on this instance.

I'm using one `HttpClient` instance for my app, so is it possible to cancel one, specific request and leave any others to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel it by passing `CancellationToken` to the async client operation and tell it when to timeout, but keep in mind this does not guarantee that it will be canceled for sure - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587037/3394884

```
var request = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"), 
                     new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Token);
```

Comment: Then I don't think it's worth using.